# The set of minimal Lebesgue measure with fixed Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}\sqrt[3]{x}, &\text{x $\leq$ 2} \\ 3\sqrt[3]{x}, &\text{x > 2} \end{cases}$$
Let $\mu_g$ be the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by $g$. Let $E \subset [-2, 3]$ and $\mu_g E = 4$. The task is to construct $E$ with such properties and minimal Lebesgue measure. I have found a way of constructing such a set by simply taking the union of intervals on which the density of $\mu_g$ (i.e. $g'$) is greater than everywhere else. Following this route I have managed to construct the following set 
$$E^* = [-a, a] \cup [2, b], \text{where $a = \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$ and $b = \frac{(4-\frac{2\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt{3}} + \sqrt[3]{2})^3}{27}$}$$It appears to be correct, but I am having trouble proving the minimality of its Lebesgue measure in the following sense: if $E \subset [-2, 3]$ and $\mu_g E = 4$ then $\lambda E >= \lambda E^*$.

I have some thoughts on the matter, but they don't seem to prove anything.

Consider the sets $A = E^* \setminus E \subset E^*$ and $B = E \setminus E^* \subset [-2, 3] \setminus E^*$. Both $E$ and $E^*$ must contain $2$ as  $\mu_g([-2, 3] \setminus {2}) < 4$. Then $2 \notin A$ and $2 \notin B$. 
$$\mu_g E = \mu_g E^* \Leftrightarrow \mu_g A = \mu_g B$$
Let $A_1 = A \cap [-a, a]$, $A_2 = A \cap [2,b]$, $B_1 = B \cap [-2, 2)$ and $B_2 = B \cap [b, 3]$.
$$\min_{A_1} f'(x) \lambda A_1 + \max_{A_2} f'(x) \lambda A_2 \leq \int_{A_1}g'(x)d\lambda(x) + \int_{A_2}g'(x)d\lambda(x) = \mu_g A = \mu_g B = \int_{B_1}g'(x)d\lambda(x) + \int_{B_2}g'(x)d\lambda(x) \leq \max_{B_1} 
f'(x) \lambda B_1 + \max_{B_2} f'(x) \lambda B_2$$
Then $\min_{A_1} f'(x) = g'(a) = \max_{B_1} f'(x)$ and $\min_{A_2} f'(x) = g'(b) = \max_{B_2} f'(x)$.
It all results in the following inequality
$$ g'(a) \lambda A_1 + g'(b) \lambda A_2 \leq g'(a) \lambda B_1 + g'(b) \lambda B_2$$

That is how far I could make it. Any further help on the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just off the top of my head: Don't you want to look where g is largest? So why isn't E concentrated near 3?

Comment: Excepting the point of discontinuity (which should be included since it has Lebesgue measure zero), you want to concentrate on where $g'$ (the derivative) is largest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result that is fairly evident from a geometric standpoint
but very tedious to confirm.

Let $S = \lim_{t \downarrow 2} g(t)-g(2)$. We see that
$m \{2\} = 0$ and $\mu_g \{2\} = S>0$.

Note that $g$ is continuous on $[-2,3] \setminus \{2\}$, differentiable on $[-2,3] \setminus \{0,2\}$ and we can write $\mu_gA = S \cdot \delta_{\{2\}}(A)+ \int_A g' dm$.

Let $\phi(M) = \mu_g(\,(g')^{-1}(\,(M,\infty) \cap [-2,3])\,) $. Note
that $\phi$ is continuous, $\phi(0) >4-S$,  $\phi$ is strictly decreasing and $\lim_{M \to \infty} \phi(M)= 0$, hence there is
some $M$ such that $\phi(M) = 4-S$.

Let $E^* = (g')^{-1}((M,\infty)) \cap[-2,3]) \cup \{2\}$.

Now suppose $E$ is such that $\mu_g E = 4$. If $2 \notin E$, we can replace $E$ by $\{2\} \cup \tilde{E}$ where $\tilde{E} \subset E $ is
chosen such that $\mu_g (\{2\} \cup \tilde{E}) = 4$ and $m(\{2\} \cup \tilde{E}) \le m E$. Hence we can assume $2 \in E$.

If $\mu_g(E^* \setminus E) = 0$ then we see that $\mu_g E^* \le \mu_g E$, so suppose
$\mu_g(E^* \setminus E) > 0$. Since $\mu_g E^* = \mu_g E$ we see that
$\mu_g(E \setminus E^*) = \mu_g(E^* \setminus E)$. By construction
we have $M \cdot m (E^* \setminus E)  \le \int_{E^* \setminus E} g'dm = \int_{E \setminus E^*} g'dm  \le M \cdot m (E \setminus E^*)$,
from which it follows that $m E^* \le m E$.

Hence $E^*$ is a minimal set.

Comment: Appears to be correct, thank you very much!

Comment: @falceeffect: The values I get for $a,b$ in the question that correspond to the $M$ above (to have $\mu_g$ measure 4) are different than the values in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The set constructed according to your method gives smaller $\mu_g$ than mine. For some reason my approach doesn't work correctly. Yours does fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: I meant $\lambda$, not $\mu_g$.

Comment: You just need to find the $M$ (which is an algebraic mess, as far as I can tell), remember that you would need $g'(a)=g'(b) = M$.

Comment: I've already found it. It is not quite messy, but not too pretty either: $M = \left(\frac{3+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}{4+\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)^2$